# Eve: 405 Methods not allowed for PATCH request

Tags: python, rest, eve

I tried to disable [concurrency-control](http://python-eve.org/features.html#disabling-concurrency-control) on Eve and trying to add another new `id_field: "new_field"`, but I am not able to make it work. I look through various post in StackOverflow but still I am not able to fix it. Could someone please help?

I disabled : `IF_MATCH = False` in the global config and:

```
schema = {
    "node_name": {
         "type": "string",
         "unique": True,
         "required": True,
    "node_type": {
         "type": "string",
         "required": True,       
    }
}
```

Config:

```
config = {
    'item_title': 'new_title',
    'additional_lookup': {
         'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
         'field': 'node_name',
     },
    'id_field': "node_name",
    'schema': schema,
}
```

And here is the url i am trying to send PATCH request:

```
url: http:localhost:5000/api/v1/resource/end_point/
```

Here

```
resource: my resource name
end_point: id_field value.
```

Could someone please help.

Comment: @nicola-iarocci could you please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled PATCH for your resource? By default, [document and collection endpoints are read-only](http://python-eve.org/features#read-only-by-default). Try adding the following to your configuration:

```
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'PUT']
```

Also, you don't want to set an `additional_lookup` on the same field serving as `id_field`, as additional lookups are read-only.

Since you are not using a ObjectID as your unique key,  you also probably need to change the default URL for the document endpoint. Try setting `ITEM_URL` to the correct regex:

> `ITEM_URL`: URL rule used to construct default item endpoint URLs. Can be overridden by resource settings. Defaults `regex("[a-f0-9]{24}")` which is MongoDB standard Object_Id format.

Comment: i removed additional lookup and now I got this error: {
"_status": "ERR"
"_error": {
"message": "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."
"code": 404
}-
}

Comment: I enabled 'PATCH' too.

Comment: If I removed my field from `addtional_lookup` then I can't even do GET request.

Comment: Hi Nicola,    Here is my regex:  `ITEM_URL = 'regex("[a-z0-9]+")'`  and here is my URL endpoints  api/v1/resource/`host1`, but still throwing the same error, I believe the regex is matched with `host1` not sure whats going on.

Comment: HI Nicola,

I am able to make it work :) thank you so much for the tips and direction:

Updated the following field and it works:

    'id_field': "node_name",                                                             
    'item_lookup_field': "node_name",                                               
    'item_url': r'regex("[\w]+")',


Thansk SJ

Comment: I am glad. Please accept the answer too, so other readers can find it more easily.